# Uploading images to Google App Engine from non-webpage client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload, blobstore, form-data

I have a Google App Engine application (Python) which needs to allow users to upload images to the blobstore. The client, rather than being a web app, will be native mobile apps. I have the following code to do uploads:

```
class ImageGetUploadURLHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write(blobstore.create_upload_url('/imgupload'))

class ImageUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    imgInfo = self.get_uploads('img')[0]
    logging.info('Uploading image %s of size %i'.format(imgInfo.filename, imgInfo.size))
    self.redirect('/echo?val=%s' % str(imgInfo.key()))
```

Where the `ImageUploadHandler` is mounted on `/imgupload`, and `/echo` is a simple handler that echoes back whatever is passed in `val` as text/plain. As of right now, I'm just using REST testing tools, as I haven't started the mobile apps yet. I did a GET to the ImageGetUploadHandler, and copied the resulting link into the testing application, where I used a POST with a multipart/form-data with an image file under the correct key to the upload URL. When I do, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid boundary in multipart form: ''
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your client seems to send a wrong multipart/form request. Create a simple html form to test the server side to make sure it's ok: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Here is some help about creating a multipart post and boundery : http://chxo.com/be2/20050724_93bf.html

Comment: @PeterKnego: I tried, I was having trouble with GAE. I'll try again.